# Using 'Protocol' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Protocol' is not supported

Tags: swift, protocols, extension-methods

I have the following swift code:

```
protocol Animal {
var name: String { get }
}

struct Bird: Animal {
    var name: String
    var canEat: [Animal]
}

struct Mammal: Animal {
    var name: String
}

extension Array where Element: Animal {
    func mammalsEatenByBirds() -> [Mammal] {
        var eatenMammals: [Mammal] = []
        self.forEach { animal in
            if let bird = animal as? Bird {
                bird.canEat.forEach { eatenAnimal in
                    if let eatenMammal = eatenAnimal as? Mammal {
                        eatenMammals.append(eatenMammal)
                    } else if let eatenBird = eatenAnimal as? Bird {
                        let innerMammals = eatenBird.canEat.mammalsEatenByBirds()
                        eatenMammals.append(contentsOf: innerMammals)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return eatenMammals
    }
}
```

The compiler does not let me compile complaining:
**Using 'Animal' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Animal' is not supported** at the point where I recursively call the function **mammalsEatenByBirds()**

I have seen some other answers but could not relate my problem to any of those.

Comment: Please read the results of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Using++as+a+concrete+type+conforming+to+protocol+is+not+supported

Comment: Compare [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878) – simple fix would just be to make the extension `extension Array where Element == Animal {...}`. Although that being said, given you're only working with the `Bird` elements, you may want to consider making it `extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Bird`, and just doing a (lazy) `flatMap` before calling in order to filter only the `Bird` elements.

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix is replacing `Element: Animal` with `Element == Animal`.

Comment: If you do it, you must cast explicitly `Bird` array to `Animal`. Like this: `let mammals = (birds as Animal).mammalsEatenByBirds()`. Thats dumb (not of you, but of Swift).